# react-instantsearch - Is there a way to add facets to customize search even more?

Tags: reactjs, algolia

I have a search page implemented in my project, and I'm needing to implement some permission access to certain records, based on roles of the user. When not using react, I'm able to utilize facets where I can create query-like statements to grab certain records, however with `react-instantsearch` I'm not sure if I can do that.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can add facets with the [Configure](https://community.algolia.com/react-instantsearch/widgets/Configure.html) widget. This looks something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { InstantSearch, Configure } from 'react-instantsearch/dom';

const App = (userID) => (
  <InstantSearch>
    <Configure facets={[userID]} />
  </InstantSearch>
);
```

Comment: Oh this is fantastic! After a bit more digging though, I'm trying to figure out if there's a way where I could do something like `<Configure facets={manager._id: User1234} />` kind of thing? I can't find much documentation on using the actual `facets` property in the documentation :/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter by item with a type institution, you can do it like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { InstantSearch, Configure } from 'react-instantsearch/dom';

const App = (userID) => (
  <InstantSearch>
    <Configure facetFilters={{[['type:institution']} />
  </InstantSearch>
);
```

To create more complex filters (AND, OR...), you can have a look at the [documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/facetFilters/?client=javascript)